# cannot run cordova application on device or emulators error running

Tags: android, cordova

When I'm trying to run my Cordova application through command line. My build is successful but running on emulator or device it gives me an error on command line

> ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to
>   install apk to d evice: Error: Could not find apk architecture: arm
>   build-type: debug ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error:
>   cmd: Command failed with exit  code 8 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to run this project

I have specified the the minimum sdk version in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

on emulator I am running API version 19, android 4.4.2 and on mobile I am running android 4.4.3 with enabled USB debugging  on Sony Xperia ultra t2.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio 2017 and Cordova 7+ had the same problem, but came to a different solution. Cordova now makes subfolder in output dir: `/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/`**debug**`/android-debug.apk`

In cordova's *GenericBuilder.js* (*build.js* now only inherit method we're looking for) in `findOutputApksHelper` script, of course, doesn't add that subdirectory to search mask:

```
.....
function findOutputApksHelper (dir, build_type, arch) {
    var shellSilent = shell.config.silent;
    shell.config.silent = true;

    var ret = shell.ls(path.join(dir, '*.apk')).filter(function (candidate) {
.........
```

So I changed it like this:

```
..........
function findOutputApksHelper (dir, build_type, arch) {
    var shellSilent = shell.config.silent;
    shell.config.silent = true;

    var subAPKMask = build_type + '\\*.apk';

    var ret = shell.ls(path.join(dir, subAPKMask)).filter(function (candidate) {
............
```

Maybe it will be helpful to someone, cause I spent two hours of life to find that.

Comment: I spent two days and still it is not working your solution has no effect

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in cordova (that only appears when using gradle).
It seems to be fixed in the current master branch (which you can use with cordova platform add android@master --usegit )

For the old version I workedaround it like this:

There is a file build.js in your cordova/lib/ folder in your project.
This file contains a function `findOutputApksHelper` which checks if the generated apks match a specific filename scheme.
By default the generated debug apks are named android-debug-unaligned.apk, however the method excludes all files that contain "-unaligned".
I modified the function like this:

```
function findOutputApksHelper(dir, build_type) {
    var ret = findApks(dir).filter(function(candidate) {
        // Need to choose between release and debug .apk.
        if (build_type === 'debug') {
            console.log("candidate: "+candidate);
            return /-debug/.exec(candidate);
        }
        if (build_type === 'release') {
            return /-release/.exec(candidate) && !/-unaligned/.exec(candidate);
        }
        return true;
    });

    ret = sortFilesByDate(ret);
    console.log("ret " + ret);
    if (ret.length === 0) {
        return ret;
}

    var archSpecific = !!/-x86|-arm/.exec(ret[0]);
    return ret.filter(function(p) {
        return !!/-x86|-arm/.exec(p) == archSpecific;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will Try This and let you know soon

Comment: I tried this and it did not solve my problem, which is similar. The emulator runs but I cannot get cordova to launch the app on emulator: "Failed to launch app on emulator: Error: Could not find apk architecture: x86 build-type: debug"

Comment: The methos is now called module.exports.findBestApkForArchitecture

Answer (score 0):

Just remove output.json file from debug/release folder. Then try again.